# urlencoded values to Model

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

so I have a url encoded string which I managed to convert to json using

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        var inputStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
        var json = inputStream.ReadToEnd();

        var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(json);
        var json3 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                                                 dict.Keys.Cast<string>()
                                                     .ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k]));
```

then I eventually converted it to a dynamic object, however what I would like to do is convert some of the properties to a collection of models. Are there any methods out there that would allow me to achieve the case below without having to write my own routine:

this is what json3 looks like:

```
>    {
"inserted[0].Property1":"dsdsdsds","inserted[0].Property2":"323","inserted[1].Property1":"dsds",
"inserted[1].Property2":"","inserted[1].Property3":"32",
"updated[0].ID":"1","updated[0].Property3":"7",
"updated[1].ID":"2","updated[1].Property3":"7","updated[1].Property4":"78",
"page":"1","size":"10","orderBy":"","groupBy":"","filter":"","aggregates":""
}
```

So I would like to get this and convert all the keys that starts with inserted[0] to a Model that we can call SomeClass that has Property1, Property2, ... Property4 esentially ending up with a List, same goes for all the keys that start with updated[x].

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have `SomeClass` with the necessary properties and its container with `inserted` and `updated` lists etc., or do you want completely generic conversion of this kind of serialization into `dynamic` object? By the way, if you know the authors of this "JSON", tell them they're doing it wrong.

Comment: hey Athari, I would like a generic conversion. I think what I will end up doing is grouping the keys by updated[x] and inserted[x], extracting the properties and their values, and building my lists that way. The json above is what comes from the telerik grid, well after converting the url encoded values anyway.

Comment: If models were specific, I could recommend `System.Windows.PropertyPath` from PresentationFramwork assembly, as it uses a similar syntax. But I don't think it will work with dynamic objects. You may find [ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface) useful.